# Dropzone event before removing a file

Tags: javascript, file, dropzone, remove-if

In [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) we have a `removedFile` event, which is fired after file is removed.

What I need is an event that is fired before file is removed, so that I can trigger removal from server and if it succeeds then will remove a file from dropzone, otherwise file from dropzone will not be removed and error message will be shown.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would make my own remove links (instead of using the default) that first sends the request to the server. On success programmatically removes the item from dropzone.

Comment: That is the last thing I will do, just want to know if there is an inbuilt way that is maybe not documented